# Access to the NIB window controls

Tags: cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I have inherited a new class from NSWindowController to implement windowDidLoad and then access to the NIB defined window controls:

```
- ( void ) windowDidLoad
{
   NSArray * controls = [ [ [ self window ] contentView ] subviews ];
   int i;

   NSRunAlertPanel( @"windowDidLoad", @"", @"OK", NULL, NULL );

   if( [ controls count ] == 0 )
      NSRunAlertPanel( @"no hay controles", @"", @"OK", NULL, NULL );   

   for( i = 0; i < [ controls count ]; i++ )
      NSRunAlertPanel( @"control", @"", @"OK", NULL, NULL );   
}
```

code execution goes fine. The NIB window is shown, but subviews has no elements. How to access the window child controls ? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> The NIB window is shown, but `subviews` has no elements.

You probably forgot to hook up the window outlet to your window. When the outlet is not hooked up, the outlet property holds `nil`, so `[self window]` returns `nil`.

Then you send messages to `nil`. I say “messages” because [every message to `nil` does nothing and returns `nil`, `0`, or `0.0` as appropriate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7). That means you send the `contentView` message to `nil`, so that returns `nil`, which means you send the `subviews` message to `nil`, so that also returns `nil`.

As I said, a message to `nil` returns `nil`, `0`, or `0.0`; when you send the `count` message to `controls`, since `controls` is `nil` as explained in the previous paragraph, that message returns `0`.

The fix is to open your nib in IB and connect your controller's `window` outlet to your window.

By the way, you should not use indexes to loop over NSArrays. There is a simpler, cleaner way to do it: [Fast Enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html).

Comment: The inherited class windowController is created programmatically. How to hook up the window outlet ? thanks,

Comment: I think you're confusing a class with an instance. The window controller object is an instance of the NSWindowController class, or of a class that inherits from NSWindowController. Doing something “programmatically” refers to doing it in one or more statements; creating a class programmatically is very difficult (not to mention pointless), so you almost certainly mean instantiating it, which is irrelevant: There is no other way to instantiate an NSWindowController. (You *could* create one in a nib, but there would be no point.)

Comment: As for connecting the outlet: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/

Comment: I did not explain it properly. I instantiate the windowController object programmatically. The question is how do I hook up the NIB window to my controller so data window is not nil ? thanks,

Comment: "The fix is to open your nib in IB and connect your controller's window outlet to your window" The controller does not exist in IB so I can not set its window outlet. Thats what I am looking for, thanks

Comment: This post seems to point in a better direction:
http://osdir.com/ml/cocoa-dev/2010-07/msg00252.html
"Did you remember to hook up the window in the nib to File's Owner's
window outlet? Did you remember to change the class identity of File's Owner to your NSWindowController subclass?"

Comment: I have created a visual tutorial for it:
http://forums.fivetechsupport.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=19373&p=102091#p102091

Comment: That's not “a better direction”, that's the direction recommended by the docs.